# How do I push an mbox file to an SMTP server?

Tags: email, smtp, mbox

I have about 2G of email in four mbox files. I want to push it into my Postfix mail system, which is listening on SMTP. What's the most reliable way to do that?

Comment: I don't think postfix can do this for you directly. Procmail is often used for this kind of thing though.

Comment: You want postfix to resend these mails to their original recipients or send them to one single specific address?

Comment: All the mail is intended for me and should be delivered locally.

Currently fetchmail retrieves mail from remote mailboxes, and pushes it to SMTP. Postfix then delivers it locally to Dovecot. I just want to do the same thing as fetchmail, but from some mbox files.